# PyQGIS use mouse and keyboard?

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to extend the QGIS function to add object with mouse and keyboard. Every time I click on add object a window appears in which I have to enter the attribute value, which should be prevented in the future (see picture).

[image]

**Concrete task**: Each time I left-click on my mouse, the number 1 should be written once by keyboard programming (PyQGIS)

Comment: There is no need to change the way QGIS is handling new objects. From the menu Settings -> Options, then Digitization -> Object Creation check Reuse last attribute values. Then digitize one object and input attribute value. Again, navigate to the Object Creation setting and check the first option (suppress formular ...) too. Now for each digitized object QGIS sets the last values without showing the attribute formular. (I am sorry if the English menu items are slightly different, but I cannot change the language setting at the moment)